# How to play x times audio in android?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-layout, service, while-loop

I am using while loop `while(mMediaPlayer.isPlaying());` in this function so, the problem is it freezes all the functionality of the device and device hangs... How to resolve??

```
public void Repeat_mantra()
    {
     mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.shri_krushna_fast);
     // mMediaPlayer.setVolume(0.2f, 0.2f);


     mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
          public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer arg0) {    

              mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.shri_krushna_fast);

              for(int i=1;i<count;i++)
              {
                  synchronized (this)
                  {                   
                          btn_count.setText(""+(i+1));  
                          if((i % 2)==0)
                          { 
                              mMediaPlayerBell=MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.bell);
                              mMediaPlayerBell.start();

                              btn_round.setText(""+(round+1));
                              round += 1;                                 

                              Log.e("count", ""+i);
                              Log.e("round", ""+round);
                         }
                          else                            
                          { 
                              Log.e("Else count", ""+i);
                              Log.e("Else round",""+round);
                           }

                          mMediaPlayer.seekTo(0);
                          mMediaPlayer.start();
                         while(mMediaPlayer.isPlaying());
                  }

           }
          }
      });    
    //  mMediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
     mMediaPlayer.start();

}
```

Comment: try with loop playback for media player  like mediaplayerobj.setLooping(true);

Comment: setLooping(true) it make audio for infinite times to play but i want to play audio x times...means my audio will play user defined times ex. 100 times.

Answer (score 0):

You should move all your code associated to playing into `run()` method of a separate thread and start it:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(){
  @Override
  public void run(){
     // place your player code here

  }
};

thread.start();
```

If you have a need to perform some operations influencing UI from such separate thread, you should execute them by `runOnUiThread()` method:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
   @Override
   public void run(){

      // change UI here

   }
});
```

Comment: can u please suggest how to do this.. if u have any answer so, please share with me with your code...

Comment: sir, can u suggest how to replace while loop in my code because i have use your thread code and asyntask also but have not success..

Comment: @user3518926 please post the code how you tried to use it and what errors occured

Comment: Sir, i am not getting any error but my device gets hang..i am using while(mMediaPlayer.isPlaying()); in my code so, this can freezes all activity of my device.. i am using play and pause button simply but this not work when media player gets start..

Comment: This is the main error--to make long lasting operations be performed in main thread, even if everything else looks quite OK. There is no way to awake your buttons if you use such approach.

Answer (score 0):

try with following when you start the player very first immediately decrement the count variable

```
int count=100;


 public void Repeat_mantra() {


    mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),
            R.raw.shri_krushna_fast);

    // mMediaPlayer.setVolume(0.2f, 0.2f);

    mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer arg0) {

            if(count<100 && count>0){

            count--;
            mMediaPlayer.start();
            }else if(count<0){
                mMediaPlayer.stop();


            }
        }
    });



}
```